# Apostrophe replaced by â€™ in mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, replace, phpmyadmin, apostrophe

I'm a complete mySQL & PHP noob, and in my table, whenever there is an apostrophe, it gets replaced by â€™. I've searched and found that it could be because my table is not UTF-8, but I changed all the collation settings in phpMyAdmin to utf8_unicode_ci, and I still get the â€™.

To be clear, I am sending the data to a PHP script from an iPhone app using NSURLConnection. In the url it loads, the apostrophe is replaced by %E2%80%99. My server is running Linux.

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: More hints: [PHP UTF-8 cheatsheet](http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make a query before storing data:

`SET NAMES utf8`.

Apparently it's `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn)` in 5.2+

Comment: Right. I will upvote if you mention the PHP function for that. Using a `SET NAMES` query is considered deprecated in PHP world :)

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophe gets urlencoded. You will have to decode it using `urldecode` on the php side, then put it into the database.